# How to toggle vimtex-log?

Tags: plugin-vimtex

[Here](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/e323c55e9669c1adb205295b06ec4463bae5b637/doc/vimtex.txt#L676) VimTex has a mapping for viewing the log. However, is open in a buffer that cannot be toggled, so I have to type: `:bd` to return to my text. This is not happening with `error buffer` where I can use `<leader>le` to hide & show errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close the log window with the `q` key or `<esc>`. But note that you mostly don't need to view the VimTeX log window as it is made more or less only for debugging purposes.